# Can't catch bad_alloc in MinGW

Tags: c++, exception, g++, mingw, try-catch

I am writing a program for a homework where I need to allocate many objects to check things on locality and performance etc. I can't seem to catch the exception thrown by `new`

```
#include "List.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <exception>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "size of List c++ : " << sizeof(List) << endl;  //16
    List * ptrList = new List();
    unsigned long var = 0;
    try {
        for (;; ++var) {
            List * ptrList2 = new  List();
            ptrList->next = ptrList2;
            ptrList2->previous = ptrList;
            ptrList = ptrList2;
        }
    } catch (bad_alloc const& e) {
        cout << "caught : " << e.what() << endl;
//  } catch (...) { //this won't work either
    }
```

Results in :

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

If I change the allocation part as :

```
            List * ptrList2 = new (nothrow) List();
            if (!ptrList2) {
                cout << "out of memory - created " << var << " nodes" << endl;
                break;
            }
```

I get a nice :

```
out of memory - created 87921929 nodes
```

Why can't I catch `bad_alloc` ?

I am on mingwin on Windows 7 x64 Pro

```
C:\Users\MrD>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.2
```

The List :

```
class List {
    long j;
public:
    List * next;
    List * previous;
    virtual long jj() {
        return this->j;
    }
    List() {
        next = previous = 0;
        j = 0;
    }
    virtual ~List() {
        if (next) {
            next->previous = this->previous;
        }
        if (previous) {
            previous->next = this->next;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You might not have enough memory left for the exception.

Comment: @Chris:Wow - never thought of that :) - any way to tell (seems absurd though - bad_alloc throws bad_alloc ?)

Comment: I'm not sure. I only thought of that because I saw it mentioned a couple days ago on a "Why use the nothrow version?" question.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler, try the example there. You might also try to allocate a buffer area at startup, then release it in new-handler (and throw), to see if maybe that's needed for the exception handling.

Comment: @Chris: I think that's unlikely. It usually gets thrown allocated on the stack.

Comment: @chris: I've never heard of such a thing, every single library I've ever seen is specially designed to not require any heap at all to throw a `bad_alloc`. (Billy, I've always seen it as a global, I've never seen it on the stack)

Comment: This looks like a MinGW bug; plain and simple. Have you talked with them?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: http://ideone.com/YN6we4 ouputs `size of List c++ : 16
caught : std::bad_alloc`, I think it's a bug in MinGW, rare as that is.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: thanks ! I tried this (using `std::set_new_handler(0);` and not `std::set_new_handler(nullptr);` and got the exact same `This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way`

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think it's more common than you'd think. The compiler is great but the MinGW support libraries are... well... bad. It's the primary reason I recommend people avoid this compiler.

Comment: @BillyONeal (and Mooing Duck), Thanks, I can't find the other question, but it does make a lot more sense to do it like that.

Comment: @BillyONeal:Well I guess I'd accept as an answer a bug report then ;)

Comment: @MooingDuck: - just copy pasted the code in  ideone.com/YN6we4 and got the same runtime error - so it is not any other staff of mine apparently. `g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o List.o "..\\List.cpp"` and`
g++ -o smaragd_hw3.exe List.o ` is the compiler invocation (I use eclipse I do not build this manually

Comment: @Billy: i think you're right that it's unlikely, and also that bad_alloc exception does not (with normal implementation) use ordinary dynamically allocated memory. however, assuming you were talking about the exception object, it can't very well be "allocated on the stack", since the stack is unwound... in practice a static area, or for c++11 one such per thread, is set aside to store the exception object. i guess you saw that yourself pretty immediately after posting. so am surprised that 2 Someones(TM) found it worthwhile to upvote that comment. it's like, SO can be pretty backwards ;-)

Comment: @Cheers: Erm, of course the exception object can stay on the stack. The stack gets unwound, yes, so logically it isn't on the stack. But physically? There's no reason it can't be there. Perhaps I should have used the "standardsese" and said "in automatic storage"

Comment: @Billy: unwinding of the stack includes executing destructors of automatic objects, which can use any amount of stack storage. i.e. the unwinding is not just popping stuff. as it executes destructors there can be activity stretches with much pushing also (although in the end popping the same amount of course). and since destructors can invoke recursive routines, there is no way to predict the amount of stack needed. which means that an exception object on the stack can easily be overwritten, and that this can't be practically prevented. sorry, i should have explained, not assumed. ok?

Comment: @Cheers: That's easily prevented by putting the exception object at the maximum extent of the stack. (e.g. the memory page used just before a stack overflow would terminate the process) (Which is, granted, functionally equivalent to "some global location") As far as the *language* is concerned however, the exception object is in automatic storage; not the free store.

Comment: @Billy: right, but no, "automatic storage" has a different meaning, namely, as you rightly used the word (even if some pedants question that), the stack. the exception object can't logically be there, and not in ordinary dynamically allocated memory either, at least not in general, so, where then? C++11 §15.1/4 "The memory for the exception object is allocated in an unspecified way, except as noted in 3.7.4.1." The latter notes that a global allocation function, i.e. the global operator new, is not called to copy an object thrown by a `throw` expression.

Comment: @Cheers: Perhaps I misspoke. What I mean by "automatic storage" is that the object is destroyed when the owning scope (in this case, a catch block) is left.

Comment: @Billy: well, that mainly boils down to some issues of terminology ("automatic storage" has a special meaning in C++, namely LIFO, and "owning" and "scope" also have special meanings). anyway, with C++11 the relevant `catch` can no longer be considered "owning" even with a lenient interpretation of the term. that's because you can hold on to the exception object, or possibly a copy of it (you don't know which), via a smart pointer. this is in support of passing exceptions across exception-unsafe code, and it impacts a bit on how compilers deal with storage for exception objects... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody volunteered [I did it](http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/unable-to-catch-bad-alloc-td7579725.html) - see especially the answer by George Koehler for some `gdb` debugging - seems it is a bug after all but <s>I won't accept my answer till this is verified</s>  - tired of waiting.

Comment: I also have seen this when wrapping up malloc with -Wl,--wrap,malloc. If i simulate a failure (just for a single malloc) when trying to allocate a string this gives me a sigsegv instead of throwing a std::bad_alloc exception. No idea why.